# azure availability set second VM shuts down first VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-availability-set

I've got two Ubuntu VMs in one availability set. When I start the second VM it takes a few minutes and the first VM stops.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, as Azure doesn't shut down other VMs in an availability set when you start another one. How did you determine this? If you had VM1 running, and start VM2, do you then see VM1 shown as **stopped** via the portal/powershell/cli?

Answer (score 0):

An availability set is basically your way to get an SLA on uptime.

It is meant for when Microsoft has to patch/fix the VM host machines, in order to avoid that they take down your VM, they fire up the other VM in the availability set and then route all traffic to that instead.

Also, if something happens to the host machine of your ubuntu instance, all traffic is routed to your other one.

So, what you are observing is expected behavior.

Comment: Thakns for your fast reply! The problem is, as soon as the first VM is shut down, the webservice I want to run is not available anymore. So basically it becomes the opposite of an availability set.

Comment: They should both be behind the same load balancer, so as long as your main image starts up with tomcat/jetty, then it should not matter. The services need to be configured to start with the machine though, as daemons or something like that (I'm no Linux expert, hehe)

Comment: @PedroG.Dias - Which part is expected behavior? Azure does *not* shut down other VMs in an availability set when another one is started.